# Existence of bijection, f, from a compact topological space to a Hausdorff topological space implies f is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

I just ran across this theorem and it's really throwing me for a loop only because I can't see what the possible use of this could be. Here's the theorem:

If $X$, a compact space, and $Y$, a Hausdorff space, has a continuous bijection $f:X\rightarrow Y$, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

The proof is simple enough to follow, and gave me a lot of insight on what a space being compact or Hausdorff implies in the bigger picture. Other than that this statement seems less than useful. Are there topologies that may be difficult to show are compact/Hausdorf? If so why wouldn't we just relate those topologies to ones we do understand? Also (and maybe this is where I should have started) what in the world is this theorem even stating when we already know bijective is equivalent to "the existence of an inverse function"?

Comment: The main assertion is continuity of the inverse function. Existence is of course obvious.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I've gotten so used to only looking at examples that are homeomorphic I completely forgot these inverses need to be continuous.